# How Do I get total number of records in Flux of server side events

Tags: mono, flux

I'm using reactive programming where the client receives a flux of event streams of Server side events then those events are consumed. Functionality wise it works. I've a problem when I try to log the count of total records in the the flux stream. Below are the code snippets.

Let's create an instance connected to the server

```
        final WebClient client = WebClient
            .builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .build();
```

And then we start the connection, subscribing to its topic

```
        final Flux<ServerSentEvent<SomeEvent>> eventStream = client.get()
            .uri("/bus/sse?id=" + subscription)
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
            .exchange()
            .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(type))
            .repeat();

        log(eventStream, "connectSSE");

        eventStream
            .doOnError(throwable -> this.onError(throwable, eventStream))
            .doOnComplete(() -> this.onComplete(eventStream));            

        subscribe = eventStream.subscribe(someServerSideEvent -> this.onEvent(someServerSideEvent , eventStream));
```

The below method handles the event

```
  private void onEvent(final ServerSentEvent<SomeEvent> content, Flux<ServerSentEvent<SomeEvent>> eventStream) {
    log(eventStream, "onEvent");
    //Code for handling event
}
```

I've a issue with the below piece of code. Actually I want to log the count of records in the stream and I was expecting it will print some numbers but it prints something like below. Need some solution without using .block(). Any help is welcome.

"Counted values in this Flux: MonoMapFuseable, caller onEvent"

```
private void log1(Flux<ServerSentEvent<SomeEvent>> eventStream, final String caller) {
    try {
        eventStream.count().map(count -> {
            LOGGER.info("Counted values in this Flux: {}, caller {}", count.longValue(), caller);
            return count;
        });
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("Counted values in this Flux failed", e);
    }
}
```